# Django Tastypie: OneToOneField nested resource and Post Save conflict

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have two models: `User` and `UserProfile`. 
User is django.contrib.auth.models, which is having one to one relationship with `UserProfile`

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.TextField()
```

Also, On creation of User, UserProfile is created using Post Save Hook on User.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

I am trying to create a new user using Tastypie. Here is my code:

```
class UserProfileResource(ModelResource):
user = fields.OneToOneField('app.api.UserResource', 'user', full=True)

class Meta:
    always_return_data = True
    authentication = authentication()
    authorization = authorization()
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    fields = ['mobile', 'address']
    always_return_data = True

def dehydrate(self, bundle, **kwargs):
    userb = bundle.data['user']
    del userb.data['password']
    return bundle    



class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        excludes = ['is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'date_joined',
                    'last_login']

    def hydrate(self, bundle):
        raw_password = bundle.data["password"]
        bundle.data['password'] = make_password(raw_password)
        return bundle
```

Now if I comment the Post Save Hook on User, and post the data in following format, everything works fine.:

```
{"user": {"email": "test@test.com", "first_name": "test123", "last_name": "test1234", "username": "test", "password": "1234"}, "mobile": "1983", "address": "dummy  address"}
```

Post Save hook is causing problem here, as on creation of User, user profile is already created, Tastypie is giving `IntegrityError`

```
(1062, "Duplicate entry '36' for key 'user_id'")
```

I can not remove post save hook and also have to create User & User Profile using API at single endpoint.

Please Help me to make post_save hook and Tastypie work together. I am  ready to modify post_save hook, UserProfile save override and Tastypie Resources to achieve this.

Note: I am on Django 1.6, Python 2.7, django-tastypie 0.12.1

Thanks!

Comment: You aren’t specifying ``AUTH_USER_MODEL`` in your settings, by any chance?

Comment: Nop. AUTH_USER_MODEL is default (django.contrib.auth.models.User)